# Loop scraping for data for multiple pages in a website using a variable in a URL

Tags: python, arrays, loops, request

I would like to loop scrape multiple pages from the URL in request2 based on the variable {event}. This code would basically rotate through the dataset 'eventid' and scrape multiple pages of the URL based on the variable {event} in request2. The problem I am having is that the code only scrapes the page for the last event from 'eventid' (991215), then stops.

```
>>> request1 = requests.get('https://www.odds.com.au/api/web/public/Meetings/getDataByRangeCacheable/?filter=events,regions,meetings&APIKey=65d5a3e79fcd603b3845f0dc7c2437f0&sportId=1&regionId[]=1&regionId[]=22&regionId[]=24&regionId[]=25&regionId[]=26&regionId[]=27&regionId[]=28&regionId[]=29&regionId[]=30&rangeStart=2020-02-19T16:00:00.356Z&rangeEnd=2020-02-20T15:59:59.356Z ')

# Data set from request1

>>> eventid = []
>>> json1 = request1.json()
>>> for id in json1.get('events'):
        ...     eventid.append(id['id'])

>>> print(eventid)
[990607, 990111, 990594, 990614, 990608, 990112, 990595, 990615, 990609, 990113, 990114, 990115, 990116, 990117, 990118, 990119, 990324, 990325, 990326, 990327, 990295, 990286, 990328, 990318, 990296, 990287, 990329, 990319, 990297, 990288, 990330, 990320, 990311, 990298, 990289, 990331, 990321, 990312, 990299, 990290, 990322, 990313, 990300, 990291, 989959, 990323, 990314, 990301, 990292, 989960, 990315, 989822, 989961, 990316, 990303, 990293, 989962, 990317, 990304, 990294, 989963, 990305, 989964, 990306, 989965, 990307, 989966, 990308, 990309, 990310, 991142, 991143, 991144, 991145, 991146, 991232, 991211, 991218, 991147, 991233, 990583, 991212, 991219, 991148, 991234, 990584, 991213, 991220, 991235, 991149, 990585, 991214, 991221, 991236, 990586, 991215]

# Code I am having trouble with

>>> for event in eventid:
         ...     request2 = requests.get(f'https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=65d5a3e79fcd603b3845f0dc7c2437f0&eventId={event}&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

Comment: Can you share your output? What i think your problem is that you are not saving the results of each eventId. Everytime your loop runs request2 gets updated. But still i don't know what exactly is your problem. I am just guessing

Comment: The output is too big to share. How do you save the result?

Comment: My theory, when you change website, eventid change too. So probably you have to get event when page change, but didnt analyzed that website, i get that problem in other websites

Comment: Is `request2` processed within the second for-loop or is it processed outside of it?

Comment: @hpollock You're overwriting the value of `request2` for every iteration. Please share all the code around the loop, so that we can be certain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code is OK, and it does extract each event in the `for event in eventid:` loop. Try the following:

```
for event in eventid:    
    request2 = requests.get(f'https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=65d5a3e79fcd603b3845f0dc7c2437f0&eventId={event}&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    tmp_json = request2.json()
    print(tmp_json['eventId'], tmp_json['eventNameFull'])
```

and the output will be:

```
990607 Ludlow Race 5 - 5234m
990111 Newcastle Race 5 - 1765m
990594 Punchestown Race 6 - 4400m
990614 Doncaster Race 5 - 5721m
990608 Ludlow Race 6 - 3512m
...
```

Comment: _The code is OK_ If it were, they wouldn't be posting on Stack Overflow, no...? As far as I can tell, the code you've shared doesn't solve what appears to be the main issue with the OP's program.

Comment: The code is OK as it properly extracts the event from the assigned URL. However, as the "for-loop" iterates over all events, when it is finished - request2 naturally contains only the data from the last extracted event.

Therefore, it is necessary to process the data as they are extracted from within the for-loop (as I showed with my code sample). I am not publishing the code before testing it.

Comment: _However, as the "for-loop" iterates over all events, when it is finished - request2 naturally contains only the data from the last extracted event._ Right, which you don't mention in your answer, you don't actually explain what's wrong. Plus, if OP now tries to use `request2` outside the loop, as they did in their original code, the issue is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
events = []
for event in eventid:
    events.append(requests.get(f'https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=65d5a3e79fcd603b3845f0dc7c2437f0&eventId={event}&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).json())

print(events)
```

You were overwriting the contents of `request2` every iteration, you should add each result to a list instead.

Comment: Can you clarify your explanation?

Comment: If you use list, or whatever it's called in python, every event ends up whole in the list like just fetched from the api, then you can do stuff like `for event in events` for displaying something related to every event.

Comment: I tried to summarize that in an edit, let me know if I got it right?

Comment: I have provided all the necessary code that I have. Your code only prints the last event.

Comment: @hpollock The code in this answer isn't working? That's bizarre...